# normal distribution clarification

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

I was given this question in my probability homework.

Given a normal population whose

**mean** is $355$

**standard deviation** is $42$

Find the probability that a random sample of $5$ has a mean between $362$ and $372$

According to the formula I am using:

$$P(Z >\frac{362-355}{\frac{42}{\sqrt{5}}})$$

$$P(Z >\frac{372-355}{\frac{42}{\sqrt{5}}})$$

From these calculations I get:

$$0.37-0.91$$

now I looked up these values in my z-table, which yields:

$$0.3557-0.1814$$

The result is $$0.1743$$

I have this as my answer but the system won't accept it as a solution. So I don't know where the mistake is. I had someone else do the same problem nd we both got the same answer.

Comment: Is 0.5371 from the z-table?

Comment: and yes. Extra help would be great if you are willing to provide

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Check the answers. Those are much better explained. It seems the system has a mistake. If you would like further explanation, I'll be glad to help.

Comment: I think these answers will do it. Thank you though.

Comment: Sure. Sorry I might have confused you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If observations are drawn from a population with mean $\mu = 355$ and standard deviation $\sigma = 42$, then a sample of size $n = 5$ will have a sample mean $\bar X$ that is normally distributed with mean $\mu = 355$ and standard deviation $\sigma/\sqrt{n} = 42/\sqrt{5}$.  Then the probability that the sample mean is between $362$ and $372$ is $$\begin{align*} \Pr[362 < \bar X < 372] &= \Pr\left[\frac{362 - 355}{42/\sqrt{5}} < \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} < \frac{372 - 355}{42/\sqrt{5}}\right] \\ &= \Pr\left[ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{6} < Z < \frac{17\sqrt{5}}{42} \right] \\
&\approx \Phi(0.905075) - \Phi(0.372678) \\
&\approx 0.171981.  \end{align*}$$
It would seem that your answer is not sufficiently precise due to rounding at too early a stage in your calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The probability is given by
$$
P\biggl(Z<\frac{372-355}{42/\sqrt{5}}\biggr)-P\biggl(Z<\frac{362-355}{42/\sqrt{5}}\biggr)\approx0.8173-0.6453=0.1720.
$$